# What is the formal definition of a macrostate?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In thermodynamics, and in particular with regards to entropy, we talk about different microstates giving rise to the same macrostate, that is the same gross overall features. This informal definition has been bothering me for some time. Is there a rigorous and formal definition of a macrostate?

Comment: Acc. to F. Rief, 'The "macroscopic state," or "macrostate," of the system is defined by specifying the external parameters of the system and any other conditions to which the system is subject.' For example, the volume of the system, Applied mag. field, etc. Energy of the system depends on these external parameters. For a particular energy, the system can be in any of the possible degenerate energy eigenstates. These eigenstates are the microstates of the system, for that particular macrostate.